# Can't export data from this page

Tags: javascript, python, html, python-3.x

I'm trying to extract my school cafeteria's menu from this web page with python with requests module and Beautiful Soup 4, but the results do not contain the parts of the menu. There seems to be a JS script that fetches the information from somewhere else. How do I extract the data?

Here's the link:
http://ruokalistat.ravitsemispalvelut.fi/#/1469e7bd-b67f-e611-80e1-38eaa712ecef

Comment: You will need to load the page into a headless browser to do that. Then after the js renders the content you get it from the newly generated DOM

Comment: Is there an easy way of doing that?

Comment: No. You need an environment that can run that content generating javascript

Comment: Can you do that with selenium?

Comment: Yes that is a headless browser